# How do I return the middle of an object

Tags: r, head

I am running a regression with state*year covariates for all U.S. states. I need to access the ones for N.J., which are probably only a few states down from where my output stops. How do I access the middle of the object while maintaining the structure of the output so that I can identify the corresponding state coefficients? Here is my code thus far:

```
g <- as.Formula(fatalityrate~sb_useage+speed65+speed70+ba08+drinkage21+log(income)+age)
g <- update(g, . ~ . + year)
g <- update(g, . - fatalityrate + sb_useage ~ . - sb_useage + primary + secondary + factor(state)*year)

sb <- plm(g, data = pnl_sb, model = "within", effect = "twoways", index = c("fips","year"))
sb_c <- coeftest(sb, vcovHC)
z test of coefficients:

                            Estimate  Std. Error     z value  Pr(>|z|)    
speed65                  -4.3506e-02  1.4132e-15 -3.0785e+13 < 2.2e-16 ***
speed70                   2.7920e-02  1.7666e-15  1.5805e+13 < 2.2e-16 ***
ba08                      1.3878e-01  7.9562e-15  1.7443e+13 < 2.2e-16 ***
drinkage21               -5.2707e-01  1.4493e-14 -3.6368e+13 < 2.2e-16 ***
log(income)               1.0611e-01  3.5164e-14  3.0175e+12 < 2.2e-16 ***
age                       1.7745e-01  1.5497e-14  1.1450e+13 < 2.2e-16 ***
primary                   4.2674e-02  9.3908e-15  4.5443e+12 < 2.2e-16 ***
secondary                -1.9863e-01  6.4951e-15 -3.0581e+13 < 2.2e-16 ***
year1984:factor(state)AL  3.2376e-01  1.0903e-14  2.9695e+13 < 2.2e-16 ***
year1985:factor(state)AL  6.5355e-01  9.5593e-15  6.8368e+13 < 2.2e-16 ***
year1986:factor(state)AL  4.7362e-01  7.2047e-15  6.5737e+13 < 2.2e-16 ***
year1987:factor(state)AL  2.8150e-01  3.1782e-15  8.8574e+13 < 2.2e-16 ***
year1988:factor(state)AL -1.4605e-01  1.1052e-14 -1.3214e+13 < 2.2e-16 ***
.
.
.
```

I thought to use the head or tail option but I have not been able to find documentation on using these commands to access the middle of a dataframe. Also I need to be able to identify the state associated with the coefficient, and head/tail command only returns the coefficient.

Comment: Without an example, we cannot provide a specific response. Generally, identify the rows of interest with `grepl` or `which` and then use that to extract them from the `sb_c` object.

Comment: turn your coefficients into a dataframe and then look the coefficient up with `grepl()` or something?  `df <- data.frame(summary(fit)$coefficients);
  df$coefficient <- rownames(df)`